# Are routers called hosts as well in a TCP/IP network?

Tags: router, ip

Is it just computers that are called hosts? Or routers are called hosts as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the real difference between host and node?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19445/what-is-real-difference-between-host-and-node-in-network)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although in some literature a host is any system that has an IP address, it more generally refers to "end systems"

A definition of host is given in [RFC1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#section-1.1.1) :

> 1.1.1  Internet Hosts
>
> ```
>      A host computer, or simply "host," is the ultimate consumer of
>      communication services.  A host generally executes application
>      programs on behalf of user(s), employing network and/or
>      Internet communication services in support of this function.
>      An Internet host corresponds to the concept of an "End-System"
>      used in the OSI protocol suite [INTRO:13].
> ```

Following this definition, routers are not hosts (nor switches for example).

Answer (score 1):

"host(s)" is not synonymous with a type of device.  Rather, it identifies a system that is "hosting" data or service(s).  A router could be considered a host in the proper context.  A router could, although there is more clear terminology for it, be considered a host for a specific route to a said subnet that needs the route.

I suppose I was speaking more to the vernacular of IT/IS circles I work within than official definition.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes textbooks refer to routers as hosts when talking about the network layer and its primary goal of moving packets from a sending "host" to a receiving "host". but more accurately, the goal is to send packets between sending and receiving IP addresses, which can be held by edge devices (hosts) and routers. I would not consider a router a host because although it has one or more IP addresses, it cannot run application layer or transport layer protocols.